# How to write a function that multiplies 2 integers without using * operator

Tags: swift, recursion

I am trying to figure out recursive operations.
I am trying to write a function that will multiply 2 integers without using the "*" operator. 
I understand it has to be essentially `Int1` added to itself `Int2` number of times, but everything I find is either C, C++ or Java.

Something along the lines of:

```
var num1: Int
var num2: Int
var result: Int

func mult() -> Int {


}
```

Once again, I know it has to be something simple, however, I am probably over-complicating things (I tend to do that)

Comment: If you have recursive C, C++, or Java examples, the idea is going to be the same in Swift. You really should take a stab at this yourself and either (a) delete this question when you figure out to do it; or, if it didn't work, (b) edit this question showing us what you tried, describe what you expected, and describe what you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try (Swift 3):

```
func mult(x: Int, y: Int) -> Int {
    if x == 0 || y == 0 {
        return 0
    }

    return x + mult(x: x, y: y - 1)
}

print(mult(x: 5, y: 10))
```

This only works if both x and y are greater than or equal to 0.

Comment: Thank You, that is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Jenny's answer by handling negative inputs:

```
func times(_ a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
    var a = a
    var b = b
    var sign = 1

    // base case for recursion
    if a == 0 || b == 0 {
        return 0
    }

    // make "a" positive and keep track of sign of result
    if a < 0 {
        a = -a
        sign = -sign
    }

    // make "b" positive and keep track of sign of result
    if b < 0 {
        b = -b
        sign = -sign
    }

    // make sure "a" is the smallest so that it finishes faster
    // by recursing fewer times
    if a > b {
        (a, b) = (b, a)
    }

    // recursive step
    // note that a * b = (1 + (a - 1)) * b = b + times(a - 1, b)
    let result = b + times(a - 1, b)

    // return result adjusting for sign
    return sign == 1 ? result : -result
}
```

Test Cases:

```
print(times(3, -7))     // -21
print(times(-3, 7))     // -21
print(times(-3, -7))    // 21
print(times(3, 7))      // 21
print(times(0, 8))      // 0
print(times(8, 0))      // 0
print(times(10000, 3))  // 30000
print(times(-3, 10000)) // -30000
```

Answer (score 0):

For *a* and *b* integers, "*a* times *b*" basically means "add *a* to itself *b* times" (or viceversa).

Assuming for simplicity that neither number is negative, this code should do exactly that:

```
func multiply(a:Int, b:Int) -> Int {

    guard a != 0 else { return 0 }
    guard b != 0 else { return 0 }

    var result = 0

    for index in 0 ..< b { 
        result += a
    }

    return result
}
```

Solutions using recursion look clever and smart at first glance, but I wouldn't use recursion unless strictly necessary. In my opinion, straightforward, non-convoluted code is best.

Comment: Lol. I agree with you, but an answer of "don't use recursion" is a curious response to "I am trying to figure out recursive operations." You might as well say, "rather than repeatedly adding a bunch of integers together, you should just multiple the two numbers." Frankly, this question smells like a homework assignment, so I suspect he really needed recursive implementation...

Comment: Oh, I missednthat part! Lol guess that disqualifies my answers. Gott aread more carefully...